# The font size of GitHub page is different from the local server

Tags: html, git

It's page on GitHub page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g1vQ.png)

It's page on local server: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEjXN.png)

Their font size is different.But why?

Comment: Those images look identical to me...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the images (and the font size) are different, double-check the path used in your `@font-face` css specification.

See "[Adding custom fonts to GitHub pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38100854/6309)" as an example.

> The root of the gitHub.io page appears to be different than the local root directory, which leads to fonts in the wrong folder.