# How do I add local font in git Pages

Tags: html, css, fonts, github-pages

I want to add an external font to my git page and I have the font in my directory but can't have it working on the page https://github.com/Aadesh9985/Aadesh9985.github.io

my page
https://aadesh9985.github.io/
I've tried different ways but nothing helps...

Also I've seen this is possible [Adding custom fonts to GitHub pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718750/adding-custom-fonts-to-github-pages)

this is what it should look like
[image: example]

Comment: Can you try with the following font declaration ?

`
@font-face {
  font-family: bi;
  src: url('https://aadesh9985.github.io/Aadesh9958.github.io/non.otf') format('opentype');
}
`

Comment: @Tom 
No not helping

Comment: Hi @aadesh-gurav, I think you've renamed your repository, can you update your question with new URLs ?

Comment: @Tom 
I've updated the links now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved
Still I don't know how to make that work but I found a similar web font and used it

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is, you can use CDN services like cloudflare. There is a free plan which you can take, host these font files and just load them with normal `link` tag.

Cloudflare: https://www.cloudflare.com/

Comment: cloudflare does not take github page domain

Comment: I'm on a low/no budget also freenom isn't working, don't know why